# How To Remove An Items From An Autocomplete Array After Being Selected

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am using an input box the select items from a database with ajax autocomplete.  I want to remove the selected item so it can not be selected again.  My code is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<input id='inpSelectRecipient' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Type recipient name here' autocomplete='off'></input>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#inpSelectRecipient").autocomplete({
    // Min Lenght Function
    minLength: 2,                   
    // Source Function
    source: function (request, response) {
        // Ajax Call
        $.ajax({
            url: '../getautocomplete.php', 
            data: request,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                // Ajax Data
                response(data);
                // Check if Results Exists
                if (data.length === 0) {
                    // Alert Message/Class
                    varModalMessage = 'No Results Found';  // Message Text
                    varAlertClass = '4';  // Error Class
                    // Alert Message
                    modalAlert(varModalMessage, varAlertClass);
                }
            }
        });
    },
    // Search Function
    search: function(event, ui) {

    },
    // Select Function
        select: function(event, ui) {
            // Variable
            var removedRecipient;
            // Create Message Recipients
            createMessageRecipients(ui.item.id);
            // Clear Input
            $('#inpSelectRecipient').val('');
            // Test
            //console.log('Receipients Array: ' + recipientsArray + ' Selected Array: ' + removedRecipient);
        },
        // Response Function
        response: function( event, ui ) {

        }
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
// Obtain Term
$term=$_GET["q"];
// Query
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE `userFirstName` LIKE '%" . $term . "%' OR `userLastName` LIKE '%" . $term . "%' ORDER BY userFirstName ");
// Json Array
$json=array();
// Array Function
while($contact=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    // JSON Array
    $json[]=array(
        'id'=>$contact["userID"],
        'value'=>$contact["userFirstName"]." ".$contact["userLastName"],
        'label'=>$contact["userFirstName"]." ".$contact["userLastName"]
     );
}
// Obtain Json
$functionReturn = json_encode($json); 
// Echo Function Return
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

I have seen other examples however none that are using ajax to obtain the autocomplete array.  Thanks so much for any help :)

Comment: I would probably use a session variable on the server that stores previously selected values in an array and eliminates them from the return results.  Without seeing your php, I don't know exactly how you should implement this, but it should be pretty easy.

Comment: @Jacob Thanks for your help.  I have added the php portion to the question, let me know if able to improve the answer.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
*you need to send selected items id to server so that in sql query it can exclude that result.

var selectedElm = [];
$("#inpSelectRecipient").autocomplete({
  ......
});

select: function(event, ui) {
  .....
  selectedElm.push(ui.item.id);
  ....
}

source: function (request, response) {
   request.exclude = selectedElm ;
   $.ajax({
    ....
    data: request,
   .....
}

and on server side just use "where not in" query.*
```

Comment: I have added the php code to my question, please let me know if able to improve the answer.  Thanks so much.  :)